# Export PDF: font not found

Tags: macos, matplotlib

I am trying to export my figure as a PDF. I run into the problem that when I want to edit it (in this case by [Graphic](http://www.graphic.com) on macOS) that the font appears not to be found by the editor. My question is, how do I solve this? Can I 'install' the fonts used by matplotlib?

---

#### Example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([0,1], [0,1])

plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

This PDF looks fine in Preview:

[image]

But in the editor, it gives gibberish:

[image]

---

#### Failing solution

Setting

```
matplotlib.rc("pdf", fonttype=42)
```

(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538040/matplotlib-output-to-pdf-for-corel-draw#40603335)).

---

#### Partly working solution

What works is to install all matplotlib's fonts. I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27818157/2646505) to find all matplotlib's ttfs, and installed them. This works and solves the problem.

*But...* This does solve the issues when LaTeX is enabled, by

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

How do I install the fonts that matplotlib uses now?

> A solution here is to export as SVG. However, for some reason this takes ages on my system (see [this bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9653)).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround. This is to convert all fonts to outlines before editing. One way to do this is with GhostScript with the option `-dNoOutputFonts`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798374/2646505):

```
gs -o file-with-outlines.pdf -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite file.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

What pdf editor are you using? I don't know how to check whether an attempt to solve this is working... but I always use this code to save images in pdf or png:

`plt.savefig('test.pdf', edgecolor='none', bbox_inches="tight")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to edit in [Graphic](http://www.graphic.com). I've edited the question as well. Unfortunately, your suggestion does not fix the problem. I suspect that it has to do with yes/no fonts being added to the PDF, or finding the possibility to convert characters to paths, such that this problem is circumvented.